# JPA using @ElementCollection with @OrderColumn but it makes exception to 'duplicate key value violates unique constraint'

Tags: kotlin, jpa, duplicates, hibernate-onetomany

First of all, I'm n.b to spring and jpa. so, Sorry for the rudimentary question.
These days I tried to make server system to location points storing using springboot + jpa + docker + postgresql /kotlin

my idea is server get client call and store locations periodically

so, I using @ElementCollection for store location item with @Embeddable
but, I got exception from springTest code

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        pos_info_pos_list
        (pos_info_id, pos_list_order, accuracy, event_time, geo_lati, geo_long) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2022-11-12 22:07:34.963  WARN 25880 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23505
2022-11-12 22:07:34.963 ERROR 25880 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pos_info_pos_list_pkey"
  Detail: Key (pos_info_id, pos_list_order)=(1, 0) already exists.
```

I'll explain the table structure below
PosInfo(one), PosData(many)
oneToMany relation
I want to use ordercolumn for performance and want posList size limitation(MAX_POS_DATA_SIZE = 200)

```
@Entity
data class PosInfo(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    var id: Long? = null
) {
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetClass = PosData::class)
    @OrderColumn
    val posList: MutableList<PosData> = mutableListOf()

    fun addPosData(posData: PosDataDto) {
        while (posList.size >= MAX_POS_DATA_SIZE) {
            posList.removeFirst()
        }
        val newData = PosData(posData.geoLati, posData.geoLong, posData.eventTime, posData.accuracy)
        posList.add(newData)
    }
}
```

PosData table

```
@Embeddable
data class PosData(
    @Column
    val geoLati: String,
    @Column
    val geoLong: String,
    @Column
    val eventTime: Long,
    @Column
    val accuracy: Int,
)
```

SpringTestCode is
first of all, insert maxSize posData then add more one data again

```
@Test
fun addPathMax() {
    val dummyPosData = PosDataDto("", "", System.currentTimeMillis(), 0)
    val dummyPosData2 = PosDataDto("yyyy", "eeeee", System.currentTimeMillis(), 0)
    val id = "KSH"
    service.tryAddUser(id, "")
    val userInfo = service.getUserInfo(id)

    assertThat(userInfo).isNotNull

    val posIndex = userInfo!!.posIndex

    val posInfo = service.getPosInfo(posIndex)
    assertThat(posInfo).isNotNull

    for (i in 0 until MAX_POS_DATA_SIZE) {
        posInfo!!.addPosData(dummyPosData)
    }

    service.updatePosInfo(posInfo!!)

    println("Next Input Check KSH_TEST")

    val posInfo2 = service.getPosInfo(posIndex)

    posInfo2!!.addPosData(dummyPosData2)
    service.updatePosInfo(posInfo2!!)
}
```

```
@Transactional
service.updatePosInfo <= it just call to crudRepository save method
```

but I got duplicate key again and again

Q1. Shouldn't the 'pos_list_order' be 'existing last +1' since the first data of the previous data was erased and the new data was inserted? why '0'?

// Key (pos_info_id, pos_list_order)=(1, 0) already exists.

Q2. Is this structure not good for updating and storing location data periodically?(using ElementCollection, should I use OneToMany?)

=To be honest, I've tried "one To Many" before. By the way, I gave up because I was tired of fixing strange build errors. I came back with "Element Collection," which I thought was easy

Thank you in advance for all the helpful comments

## ===========================
= I already tried before below

OneToMany with mapped, but it made many error and when I tried insert more value, it was made all delete row and re-install all and + newer again

ElementCollection looks simple, but it was made duplicated exception again and again
I already checked using below

```
@CollectionTable(
    name = "pos_data",
    joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "pos_info_id")]
)
```

```
JpaRepository.save then flush   doesn't work
```

but same result, I don't know why.. really sad

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution

Now this problem was caused by my poor understanding of 'Transactional'

it's fixed with below annotation

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

```
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    @Rollback(false)
    @Test
    fun addPathMax() {
        val dummyPosData = PosDataDto("", "", System.currentTimeMillis(), 0)
        val dummyPosData2 = PosDataDto("yyyy", "eeeee", System.currentTimeMillis(), 0)
        val id = "KSH"
        service.tryAddUser(id, "")
        val userInfo = service.getUserInfo(id)

        assertThat(userInfo).isNotNull

        val posIndex = userInfo!!.posIndex

        val posInfo = service.getPosInfo(posIndex)
        assertThat(posInfo).isNotNull

        for (i in 0 until Constants.MAX_POS_DATA_SIZE) {
            posInfo!!.addPosData(dummyPosData)
        }

        service.updatePosInfo(posInfo!!)

        println("Next Input Check KSH_TEST")

        val posInfo2 = service.getPosInfo(posIndex)

        posInfo2!!.addPosData(dummyPosData2)
        service.updatePosInfo(posInfo2!!)
    }
```

I thought service already including 'Transactional' annotation
so it can be made query persist context to database
but it was not